# Autohotkey with unicode and KeyWait / Long press

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like a hotkey that changes a s to a š if s is hold down for a time. The "s" key doesn't work anymore with my version. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
s::
If (KeyWait,s,T0.3){
    If ErrorLevel
        
        Send {U+0161} 
}
return

return
```

I use AHK 1.1.33.10 on a Win10 machine. The script is saved with ANSI coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s:: ; The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used
    KeyWait, s, T0.3
    If ErrorLevel   
    {
        KeyWait, s  ; waits for s to be released 
        Send {U+0161}
    }
    else
        Send s
return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm